# 3 colum layout on bootstrap losing its shape

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a 3 columns design where the first column has a fixed width of 630px, the middle column should take all available space and the third column has a fixed width of 200px.

I set it up using bootstrap Flex, with flex-fill in the middle column. It looks all dandy but when I start filling up the middle section, it grows eating the space of the last one.
The code, simplified, looks like this:

```
//body css: height: 100%, oveflow: hidden
<div class="mainContainer d-flex flex-row w-100"> //css: height 100vh, 
  <div class="leftColumn d-flex">
     //inner content ar boxes with fixed width leaning to the 600px
     //this part looks perfect
  </div>
  <div class="MainArea flex-fill d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="MainAreaUpperRowOfCards flex-fill d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
      // here I add cards with fixed size, they are lied down 
      // in a row, and they wrap nicelly.
      // But when they wrap this section starts to grow eating the
      // third colum's space
    </div>
    </div class="MainAreaLowerRow  d-flex flex-row justify-content-center"> 
      //css: height: 250px, margin-bottom: -60px
      //here are some cards that only show the upper part, hence the -60px
    </div>
  <div>
  <div class="RightColumn d-flex flex-column"> //css: width 220px; background and magins..
    //here some cards with players information
    //this is the column being eaten.
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like at the beginning and after adding some cards:
[image]

[image]

So I have two questions:

1. How do I fix the width of the right-most column? (green arrow in the picture)
2. How do I remove the space on the wrapping of the cards? (red arrow in the picture)

I added an animation for convenience:

[image]

Comment: Heya @Javirs. I noticed a typo on the `RightColumn` Div and I just wondered if this might be affecting anything you are trying in that column .... `flex-colum` with no `n`.

Comment: wow, eagle eye :)  I fixed the typo. unfortunately, this came when simplifying the code for the question, the actual page I have it properly written and still doesn't work. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `width: 220px;` to `min-width: 220px;`.
2. It's hard to help you without a live demo. Try to remove `flex` classes one by one and see if any of these classes are causing this space.

Comment: 1 was fixed with the min-width. As for two, I will try to create another question with more specific details. Thanks